# How to increase light samples for world volumetric scattering only

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, volumetrics, world

How do I increase volumetric light samples without increasing pathtracing samples for physical surfaces.

I want to improve only that part, that is the samples for the scattering through the medium, not the bounces over textured surfaces in my scenes. Else the render times will bump up too much without being useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Branched Path Tracing** for doing this:

[image]

Number after "Volume" multiply samples of volume on that value

Comment: That's great, does it work with GPU Rendering ?

Comment: @mayorc Yes, of course

Comment: It does but it can cause GPU "timeouts" in certain situations where the GPU goes unresponsive so Windows automatically resets the driver.

Comment: This totally doesn't work for me. For whatever reason, world volume scattering completely disappears when using BPT.